# Base64 trim data:^mime^;base64, from base64 data

Tags: javascript, base64

I try to strip some string from base64 data with the following script:

```
var base64Data="data:image/png;base64,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"
var newbase64Data=base64Data.replace('/data:\w*\/\w*;base64,/gm','')
console.log("New Base 64 Data",newbase64Data)
console.log("\n\n")
console.log("Old Base 64 Data",base64Data)
```

But for some reason even thogh the regexp matches it does not replace the data. DO you fellows have any idea why doas this happen?

Comment: And where exactly is the part before `data:` in your input string, that ` \b` is supposed to match …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the regular expression outside `'` or `"` quotes. Resulting this script:

```
var base64Data="data:image/png;base64,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"
var newbase64Data=base64Data.replace(/data:\w*\/\w*;base64,/gm,'')
console.log("New Base 64 Data",newbase64Data)
console.log("\n\n")
console.log("Old Base 64 Data",base64Data)
```